# Custom fonts on local drive do not work

Tags: css, url

While learning CSS, I have written following code to use Google font which I have placed on local hard disk.
The html file works if it is saved in font folder, but does not work in different folder.  Please note that 
I am not working through any server.  After saving file in another folder am double-clicking it.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">


        <head>

            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


            <title>Custom Fonts</title>

            <style>
                @font-face {
                font-family: 'Abel-regular';
                src: url('file://G:/JavaPrgsJGD/fonts/Google-fonts/Abel/Abel-regular.ttf');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                }       
            </style>  

            <style type="text/css">

                .ngs-h3 {font-family: 'Abel-regular'; font-size: 30px; color: green;}
                .ngs-p  {font-family: 'Abel-regular'; font-size: 20px; color: blue;}

            </style>

            <script>

            </script>  

        </head>


        <body>

            <h3 class="ngs-h3">Technical assessment of a movie</h3>

            <p class="ngs-p">
                Many people see the movies and immediately after completion of the show, when asked by news channels,
                they simply brush aside the movie saying, "It's a bogus movie" without realizing that what goes in for
                bringing a movie to a cinema theatre for viewers, but of course, they have spent money and time to 
                watch a movie, they at least deserve a free opinion.
            </p>

            <p class="ngs-p">
                However, this forum is not about personal likes and dislikes of down-to-earth movie-goer.  This forum
                is for students who are pursuing their technical studies in film industry.  Therefore, let us concentrate
                on technical aspects of a movie.
            </p>

        </body>


    </html>
```

Am I doing a mistake?  Please guide me and throw some light on use of local files with and without server.
Thanks.
NG SHAIKH.

Comment: Maybe just remove `file://` in your URL.

Comment: when using local files the reference **starts from your current file** (in your case its the HTML file). Mention the URL from this HTML file and not complete path including G:/ drive etc. To get a clear picture may be you can tell where your HTML file is placed along with the font file(`Abel-regular.ttf`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally strongly discourage the use of absolute file paths when working with front-end web technologies like CSS. You could put the font in a `./font` folder and use an absolute path, or use the CDN provided by

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Abel-regular';
    src: url('./fonts/Abel-regular.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
} 

// or

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel');
```

Comment: This works excellent and your suggestion is valuable.  It will be better to follow the same.  However, I made a minor change in the path, i.e. file:///G:/JavaPrgsJGD/fonts/Google-fonts/Abel/Abel-regular.ttf and it worked in Chrome and Safari but did not work in Mozilla and IE.  Can you throw some light on the same, please?

Comment: Not all browsers support all features. Chrome and Safari support the most features, while IE and Opera-mini support the least. Although that is my theory about this, I could be wrong.